# Nested for loop not updating records - inner most loop not working

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, counter

I am trying to add records to a set of names based on results fetched from other function.

```
int i=0;
int j=0;

for(DataObject name:wsdlNameList.get(i).getRows()) {
    System.out.println("Name size is : " + name.size());

    for(DataObject service :wsdlServiceList.get(i).getRows()) {
        System.out.println("service size is : " + service.size());

        for(DataObject request:  wsdlServiceRequestList.get(j).getRows()) {
            System.out.println("request name  is: " + request.get("dataName"));
            service.add(serviceBinder.putLocal("dataName_"+j,request.get("dataName"));)
        }
        j++//this is inner most loop
    }
    i++; // this is sub-names for loop
}
i++;  // this is name list for loop
```

In this scenario the outer 2 loops are working fine but the inner most loop ends up updating only the first record .

Eg :

A and B are 2 records which are called Name

sub-records under A and B are :

A has sub-names C,D

B has sub-names E,F,G

Under the sub-records I am trying to add some data which are like :

C has 2 records- 1 and 2

D has 1 record- 3

E has 3 records -4,5 and 6

and likewise.

With above code only C is being updated with values 1 and 2. Rest of records are not being updated at all.
Please provide some inputs on how to get this update part working .

Regards,
Srinath

Comment: I ahve no idea what your code is supposed to do. But I suppose you are having some issues with the counters in the loop and their position and intitalization

Comment: Please post the full code with a correct indentation.

Comment: You could try adding the loop variables inside the for loops. I mean inside the braces

Comment: why do you have twice `i++;`? Also the `;` is missing at `j++`

Comment: dude, debug line by line. you will get whats wrong.

Comment: Possible hint: extract all you `something.get(xxx).getRows()` into local variables

Comment: I think your whole loop is running only once. Debug it. wsdlNameList.get(i).getRows() might be returning single record.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs . Got it working with correct initialization of counters.